# Why do some PhD programs recruit only a handful of students and other recruit more than 100?

Tags: phd

See [this](https://szkolydoktorskie.uw.edu.pl/en/recruitment-2020-2021-3/?school=sdns). This university recruits only 5 students in the Faculty of Education.

Now, see [this link](https://www.ulisboa.pt/en/curso/doutoramento/education). They admit 110 Ph.D. students per year. They have [79 faculty members](http://www.ie.ulisboa.pt/instituto/pessoas/pessoas-docentes).

Why do some Ph.D. programs recruit only a handful of students and others recruit more than 100?

Is the recruitment size only dependent on the number of research-faculty or some other factors that are also involved?

Comment: It depends on the size of the faculty, certainly. The number itself gives no indication.

Comment: Some faculty, from departments which has something to do with experiments, would take more than 1 student per year.. So, I do not see what could be a problem here...

Comment: A PhD program that admits 3 students per year is not necessarily good either. It’s pretty context dependent.

Comment: The polish graduate school has 10 potential supervisors in the faculty of education, so the student/supervisor ratio, for what it's worth, isn't *hugely* different (0.5 vs 1.4 graduate students per supervisor).

Comment: Also, are you sure both programs admit new students every year, every semester, or every three years...?

Comment: @henning--reinstateMonica, so, is it only about the number of faculty members and nothing else?

Comment: @henning--reinstateMonica, the Polish program is admitting 5 students each year from 2017. I am not sure about the Portuguese program.

Comment: @user366312 no, I wouldn't say so. It's just that the raw number of admitted students doesn't say much. The ratio of applications and admitted students would give an indication of the school's exclusivity or how "in demand" it is. but there are many other factors that matter, like the school's resources, the reputation of its teachers, the job placement of its alumni, it's network, etc. If you are asking because you want to decide where to apply, however, your individual "fit" is more important than those "objective" indicators.

Comment: @henning--reinstateMonica, the things are u indicating, are generally uses as parameters in the university-rankings. r u suggesting me to consult various university rankings?

Comment: Basically nothing in the real world is ever dependent on only one other thing.  Think more broadly about all the resources, beyond just faculty headcount, that are needed in order to educate graduate students.  Realize that different programs have different amounts of these resources.  And many of these resources can also be used for other things besides graduate education, so it also depends on how the program chooses to allocate those resources.

Comment: Lisbon may be limited by state funding in different departments?

Comment: @JonCuster, what? Lisbon is limited? It charges tuition fees.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reliability of a program depends on many things as does the number of slots available in a given year. I have no reason to doubt that the University of Lisboa is anything but reputable.

But, if they are willing to admit up to 110 students in a given year it doesn't necessarily mean that they will. They will apply some standards to every application and might fall short of the goal. The goal might change from year to year depending on graduation and drop-out rates. It might be half the next year, though unlikely.

But the reliability depends on the rate of graduation and where the graduates wind up and not on the absolute size of the program. In fact, there may be many specialties within such a faculty, so it may not seem so large to any particular student.

But a given faculty member can probably handle three or four (more?) doctoral students at a time if they are in different stages of their programs. Some can handle many more, depending on the organization.

Look to other factors.

I was in a large program, though not quite that big. Things have gotten bigger since that time, also. But the research seminar I was in had about three faculty members and half a dozen students. Graduate classes had about 30 students, and the entire graduate student population was spread over many courses. It can work and still have high quality. In fact there can be a certain synergy that comes with a large faculty.